# Android doesnt execute normal Java class

Tags: java, android, class, methods, static

Hello I have the following code in an Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    NamazTimesManager nt = NamazTimesManager.getInstance(lm);
            ...
   }
}
```

and `getInstance()` is a static method in a normal Java class (same package as the activity):

```
public static NamazTimesManager getInstance(LocationManager lm) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new NamazTimesManager(lm);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I have debugged everything, but he never gets to the static method. Instead I get some source not found, classloader etc.. exceptions. LocationManager is also initialized correctly....I dont know what to do. Please help!

I get the following exceptions:

```
02-09 11:51:34.463: W/dalvikvm(12270): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f9a600)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.khuddam.namazapp/de.khuddam.namazapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at de.khuddam.namazapp.NamazTimesManager.<init>(NamazTimesManager.java:41)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at de.khuddam.namazapp.NamazTimesManager.getInstance(NamazTimesManager.java:29)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at de.khuddam.namazapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    ... 11 more
```

Constructor:

```
protected NamazTimesManager(LocationManager lm) {
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    LatitudeLongitude ll = new LatitudeLongitude(latitude, longitude);
    TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    boolean dst = false;

    sunriseAPI = Sun.sunriseTime(cal, ll, gmt, dst);
    sunsetAPI = Sun.sunsetTime(cal, ll, gmt, dst);

    String sunriseString = sunriseAPI.getHours() + ":" + sunriseAPI.getMinutes();
    String sunsetString = sunsetAPI.getHours() + ":" + sunsetAPI.getMinutes();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    try {
        sunriseDate = format.parse(sunriseString);
        sunsetDate = format.parse(sunsetString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception being thrown? Please post the logcat

Comment: Ok i've posted the log

Comment: What does the `NamazTimesManager` constructor do? I'm pretty sure you are passing a null `LocationManager` to it

Comment: It only gets the last known location, gets the longiutede etc...

Comment: Post the constructor please, and also post how you are calling the `getInstance` method

Comment: Ok I've posted the constructor and the call

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 11:51:34.533: E/AndroidRuntime(12270):    at de.khuddam.namazapp.NamazTimesManager.<init>(NamazTimesManager.java:41) ` which is line 41?

Comment: double longitude = location.getLongitude();

Comment: If your stack trace is from the same version of code that you posted, then `location` is null.  Trace it back through your code.

Comment: Looks like yet another null location from getLastKnownLocation question. This method will return null until you've had a location fix

Comment: the thing is, when i debug, i dont even get until that line... it stops debugging as soon as i enter `getInstance`

Comment: `it stops debugging` - what does this mean?  `getInstance` will always fail since you have a bug in the constructor.  NickT has the answer.  You must test for null and respond accordingly, or change your design to use a location listener.

Comment: I dont even reach the constructor call...the debugger never reaches `getInstance` . plus im executing/debugging directly on my phone and all GPS services are enabled.

Comment: Okay I will try the location fix stuff. Ok thanks a lot guys for your help! im new here, how can i recommend you guys??

Comment: `how can i recommend you guys` - no need.  Just come back and ask more questions, then when someone is able to answer your question, give them the rep points by accepting their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check line 41 of namazTimeManager, perhaps your lm variable in the constructor is null. You should probably test your input before using it.

PS: i have'nt read the comments before posting, nickT has probably the answer.